# getting the data from dynamically created edit text fields and send them to the webservice after clicking upload button

Tags: android, web-services, button, dynamic, upload

I am trying to get the data from the webservice and create dynamic custom fields according to the response from the webservice. Then the user will fill the fields and then after clicking the upload button it will send the data from the dynamic custom fields to the webservice and then start to upload. I wonder that how can I get the data from the custom fields because they are created dynamically I can not reach them. Here is my code. Here is my picture that I created the fields after getting the response from the webservice I need your help.

[image]

```
package com.isoft.uploader;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class UploaderActivity extends Activity 
{
ArrayList <Response> WebData= new ArrayList<Response>();
public static final int SELECT_VIDEO=1;
public static final String TAG="UploadActivity";
String path="";
final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
final String SERVICEURL = "http://192.168.10.177/androidws/isandroidws.asmx";
final String METHOD_NAME1="OzelVeriAlanlariniGetir";
final String METHOD_NAME="KullaniciGiris";
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button enter=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Enter);
    final EditText username=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    final EditText password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    final  AlertDialog ad=new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    enter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //request code for Webservice
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            //sending the username to the webservice
            request.addProperty("kullaniciAdi",username.getText().toString());
            //sending the password to the webservice
            request.addProperty("password",password.getText().toString());
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            //Putting the request in an envelope
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(SERVICEURL);
            Object response = null;
            try
            {
                 transport.call("http://tempuri.org/"+METHOD_NAME, envelope);
                 //getting the response from the webservice
                 response= envelope.getResponse();
            }
            catch(Exception exception)
            {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }//end of catch
            if(response!=null && Integer.parseInt(response.toString()) != 0)
            {
                openGaleryVideo();
            }//end of if
            else
            {
                ad.setMessage("Lütfen Kullanıcı Adınızı ve Şifrenizi Kontrol Ediniz.");
                ad.show();  
            }//end of else
        }//end of onClick method    
    });//end of OnclickListener method
}//end of onCreate method
public void openGaleryVideo()
{
    Intent intent=new Intent();
    intent.setType("video/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Video"),SELECT_VIDEO);
}//end of openGaleryVideo method

public String getPath(Uri uri)
{   
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}//end of getPath method

//Response Class
public class Response
{
    int Id;
    String Name;
    String Type;
    String Value;
    String DefaultValue;
    int Flag;
    int Index;
}//end of Response class

//onActivityResult
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_VIDEO) 
        {
            Uri videoUri = data.getData();
            path=getPath(videoUri);
            ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView(this);
            LinearLayout layout=new LinearLayout(this);
            layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
            scroll.addView(layout,new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            setContentView(scroll);             
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME1);
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            //İsteğimizi zarf'a koyuyoruz
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(SERVICEURL);
            final  AlertDialog adr=new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
            Object response1=null;
            try
            {
                 transport.call("http://tempuri.org/"+METHOD_NAME1, envelope);
                 //getting the response from the webservice
                 response1 =envelope.getResponse();
                 JSONArray jArray= new JSONArray(response1.toString());
                 for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
                 {
                     JSONObject json_data= jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                     Response result= new Response();
                     result.Id= json_data.getInt("Id");
                     result.Name= json_data.getString("Name");
                     result.Type= json_data.getString("Type");
                     result.Value=json_data.getString("Value");
                     result.DefaultValue=json_data.getString("DefaultValue");
                     result.Flag=json_data.getInt("Flag");
                     result.Index=json_data.getInt("Index");
                     WebData.add(i,result);
                 }//end of for loop     
            }//end of try 
            catch(Exception exception)
            {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }//end of catch

            for(int j=0;j<WebData.size();j++)
            {
                TextView t= new TextView(this);
                t.setText(WebData.get(j).Name);
                layout.addView(t);
                if("Type"=="datetime")
                {
                    EditText datetime= new EditText(this);
                    datetime.setId(j);
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy/MM/dd" ); 
                    datetime.setText(sdf.format( new Date()));
                    layout.addView(datetime);

                }//end of if

                else if("Type"=="int")
                {
                    EditText integer= new EditText(this);
                    layout.addView(integer);
                }//end of else if
                else
                {
                    EditText nvarchar= new EditText(this);
                    layout.addView(nvarchar);
                }//end of else 

            }//end of for loop
            Button button= new Button(this);
            button.setClickable(true);
            button.setText("Yükle");
            layout.addView(button);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
        }//end of If request code
    }//end of If result code
}//end of onActivityResult
}//end of main
```

Comment: Dont, ask questions repeatedly, this program have many question from your account, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469716/how-to-create-a-scrollable-layout

Comment: I am developing the application and the questions are useful for the other users too. They are getting the answer and learn as I learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood right, your problem is getting the data from the dynamically created fields. You could solve it by saving the dynamically created `EditText` in your class.

Here's your code saving the fields (I didn't check the syntax). I've marked the changed blocks with //BUBBLE comment.

```
package com.isoft.uploader;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class UploaderActivity extends Activity 
{
  ArrayList <Response> WebData= new ArrayList<Response>();
  public static final int SELECT_VIDEO=1;
  public static final String TAG="UploadActivity";
  String path="";
  final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
  final String SERVICEURL = "http://192.168.10.177/androidws/isandroidws.asmx";
  final String METHOD_NAME1="OzelVeriAlanlariniGetir";
  final String METHOD_NAME="KullaniciGiris";

  // BUBBLE
  private List<EditText> dynaFields = null;

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      Button enter=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Enter);
      final EditText username=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
      final EditText password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
      final  AlertDialog ad=new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
      enter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
          {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View arg0) 
          {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          //request code for Webservice
          SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
          //sending the username to the webservice
          request.addProperty("kullaniciAdi",username.getText().toString());
          //sending the password to the webservice
          request.addProperty("password",password.getText().toString());
          SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
          envelope.dotNet = true;
          //Putting the request in an envelope
          envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
          HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(SERVICEURL);
          Object response = null;
          try
          {
          transport.call("http://tempuri.org/"+METHOD_NAME, envelope);
          //getting the response from the webservice
          response= envelope.getResponse();
          }
          catch(Exception exception)
          {
            exception.printStackTrace();
          }//end of catch
          if(response!=null && Integer.parseInt(response.toString()) != 0)
          {
            openGaleryVideo();
          }//end of if
          else
          {
            ad.setMessage("Lütfen Kullanıcı Adınızı ve Şifrenizi Kontrol Ediniz.");
            ad.show();  
          }//end of else
          }//end of onClick method    
          });//end of OnclickListener method
    }//end of onCreate method
  public void openGaleryVideo()
  {
    Intent intent=new Intent();
    intent.setType("video/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Video"),SELECT_VIDEO);
  }//end of openGaleryVideo method

  public String getPath(Uri uri)
  {   
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
  }//end of getPath method

  //Response Class
  public class Response
  {
    int Id;
    String Name;
    String Type;
    String Value;
    String DefaultValue;
    int Flag;
    int Index;
  }//end of Response class

  //onActivityResult
  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
      {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_VIDEO) 
        {
          Uri videoUri = data.getData();
          path=getPath(videoUri);
          ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView(this);
          LinearLayout layout=new LinearLayout(this);
          layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
          layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
          scroll.addView(layout,new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
          setContentView(scroll);             
          SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME1);
          SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
          envelope.dotNet = true;
          //İsteğimizi zarf'a koyuyoruz
          envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
          HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(SERVICEURL);
          final  AlertDialog adr=new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
          Object response1=null;
          try
          {
            transport.call("http://tempuri.org/"+METHOD_NAME1, envelope);
            //getting the response from the webservice
            response1 =envelope.getResponse();
            JSONArray jArray= new JSONArray(response1.toString());
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
            {
              JSONObject json_data= jArray.getJSONObject(i);
              Response result= new Response();
              result.Id= json_data.getInt("Id");
              result.Name= json_data.getString("Name");
              result.Type= json_data.getString("Type");
              result.Value=json_data.getString("Value");
              result.DefaultValue=json_data.getString("DefaultValue");
              result.Flag=json_data.getInt("Flag");
              result.Index=json_data.getInt("Index");
              WebData.add(i,result);
            }//end of for loop     
          }//end of try 
          catch(Exception exception)
          {
            exception.printStackTrace();
          }//end of catch

          // BUBBLE create a list with the exact size of input fields
          this.dynaFields = new ArrayList<EditText>(WebData.size());

          for(int j=0;j<WebData.size();j++)
          {
            //BUBBLE: instantiate and add the current field to the list and view
            EditText newField = new EditText(this);
            this.dynaFields.add (newField)
            layout.addView(newField);

            TextView t= new TextView(this);
            t.setText(WebData.get(j).Name);
            layout.addView(t);
            if("Type"=="datetime")
            {
              //BUBBLE
              newField.setId(j);
              SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy/MM/dd" ); 
              newField.setText(sdf.format( new Date()));

            }//end of if

          }//end of for loop
          Button button= new Button(this);
          button.setClickable(true);
          button.setText("Yükle");
          layout.addView(button);
          button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void onClick(View arg0)
              {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub

              }
              });
        }//end of If request code
      }//end of If result code
    }//end of onActivityResult
}//end of main
```

In a nutshell, I've created an ArrayList of `EditText`

```
private List<EditText> dynaFields = null;
```

Then the list have been instantiated right before the fields creation:

```
// BUBBLE create a list with the exact size of input fields
this.dynaFields = new ArrayList<EditText>(WebData.size());
```

And finally, once the fields were created, I've added them to both the list and the view:

```
// instantiate and add the current field to the list and view
EditText newField = new EditText(this);
this.dynaFields.add (newField)
layout.addView(newField);
```

I've made some small simplifications in your if statements, so I could use just one EditText object.

To get the components, just iterate through the array in the onClick method:

```
public void onClick(View arg0)
{
    TextField currText;
    for (currText : UploaderActivity.this.dynaFields) {
     // TODO: get the current EditText text and have fun!
    }    
}
```

Comment: so you are suggesting to put all the fields into an arraylist. Then in the click method I should create a for loop to get all the data am I right?

Comment: Exactly! Check the modified answer.

Comment: thanks for help can u suggest me a way how can I put this data as a json object to send back to the webservice?

Answer (score 2):

set tags on your EditText objects when create them (result.Id), then browse through your main layout, then

```
int mainChildsCount = mainGroup.getChildCount();
for(int i=0;i<mainChildsCount;i++){
    View v = mainGroup.getChildAt(i);   
    if(v instanceof EditText){
        //recognize them here by their tags     
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont understand what you are talking about exactly sorry.

Comment: mainGroup is the layout where you add your EditText objects. In your case I think it's the LinearLayout layout; Browse through it's views and find your dynamically added EditTexts.

Answer (score 0):

Take

```
int dynId = 1001;
```

Now, when you are creating EditTexts dynamically, set their ids by using

```
.setId(dynId++);
```

Then at the time of sending EditTexts' data to web-service;
retrive values from EditTexts by getting them using ID you have seted at the time of creating.

At time of retriving, you can start retriving using 1001 and increment them by 1.

---

use this :

```
    String unm, pwd;

    YourComponent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  //  OR  In  onClick

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0)
                {
                     unm = username.getText().toString();
                     pwd = password.getText().toString();
                }
            });
```

Now, use these `unm` and `pwd` strings.

You can get the components by their ID's

```
for (int i = 1001; i < 1001 + componentCount; i++) {
  View currView = getViewById (i);
  if (currView instanceof EditText) { 
      EditText currentComponent = (EditText) currView;
  }
}
```

Comment: I am already sending the password and username my problem is sending the data fields shown in the picture

Comment: Im not interested in ids  @Chintan Raghwani

Comment: I also answering the questions, to make other learn what I know, so just accept it if you like, other-wise leave it simply.

Comment: I am not trying to be rude I just want to warn you to help me. I am not interested in ids I need to get the data from the fields. Sorry for misunderstood.